# Searching between dates using substrings in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, search

I'm trying to search for all appointments between to dates in an mysql database. The date is in this format.

```
 2012-07-26
```

Here is the code I'm using to select the relevant appointments from drop down selection boxes on another page.

```
    AND SUBSTRING(startDate, 6, 2) >= $month
    AND SUBSTRING(startDate, 6, 2) <= $month2 
    AND SUBSTRING(startDate, 9, 2) <= $day 
    AND SUBSTRING(startDate, 9, 2) <= $day2
```

The problem I have is that if I select a day like 02, then the results will only be days earlier than 02 on any month. Whereas I need something more like;

```
 SUBSTRING(startDate, 6, 5) <= '$month2'-'$day2'
```

I'm just not sure how to phrase it correctly.

Comment: The dates would be better stored as MySQL `DATE` fields instead of strings, then you can use a `BETWEEN` clause.

Comment: It's stored as DATETIME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should MySQL's date functions instead of `SUBSTRING` assuming your column is of `DATE` or `DATETIME` type.

Relevant date functions:

- `DAY()`
- `MONTH()`

New code:

```
AND MONTH(startDate) >= $month
AND MONTH(startDate) <= $month2
AND DAY(startDate) <= $day
AND DAY(startDate) <= $day2
```

You may also be able to use the `BETWEEN` operator.

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Computer says no because it doesn't seem to recognise the different parts of the date in the string.

Comment: What do you mean the computer says no? Try slapping it.

Answer (score 0):

why not something like:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE startDate BETWEEN '2012-07-25' AND '2012-07-27'
```

or if you need a dynamic range

```
WHERE startDate BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND (now() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

Doing string operations on date values is usually not necessary. MySQL has a very nice set of [date manipulation/retrieval/formatting functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) that take care of pretty much everything.